# How do you write routes to call a method from a controller with specific arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to make an api call to my application that calls a method that lives in the api controller and takes two arguments. So the url would look like this:

```
mydomain.com/api/method_in_api_controller/method_argument1/method_argument2
```

I've looked through the rails guide but I'm still unclear and it's a bit outside the scope of my experience. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your route:

```
get 'whatever/url/:first_arg/:second_arg' => 'my_controller#my_action'
```

Then in your controller you can access `:first_arg` and `:second_arg` through `params`.

```
def my_action
  first_arg = params[:first_arg]
  second_arg = params[:second_arg]
end
```

Comment: For completeness: You can also make second argument optional using brackets `'whatever/url/:first_arg(/:second_arg)'`

Comment: @BroiSatse a new thing to add to my experience :)